# How to return from xdg-open within a shell script

Tags: command-line, xdg-open, xdg

I have some shell functions which allow me to quickly open something in my browser, for example:

```
issue () {
    if [[ -z "$1" ]]
    then
        xdg-open "https://github.com/myname/myrepo/issues/$(git branch | grep '*' | grep -Poh '\d+')"
    else
        xdg-open "https://github.com/myname/myname/issues/$1"
    fi
}
```

This function loads in my shell startup scripts and it works fine, the repo issue opens in my browser as expected, however I have to manually exit from the function in my terminal with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> before I'm able to type again in my terminal.

Comment: Related: [Regain control after opening firefox via terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802428/regain-control-after-opening-firefox-via-terminal)

Comment: @steeldriver less applicable here: xdgopen already detaches from the terminal. In my opinion, the terminal is already released here, but is cluttered by the output of the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xdg-open` detaches the command it runs from the terminal, so probably your terminal is freed. Only, you see some output of the browser rather than the command prompt. Just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or give the command `clear` to return to a neat terminal prompt.

You could, for aestetic reasons, redirect terminal output to `/dev/null` by adding `1>/dev/null 2>&1` after the command. Alternatively, prepend the command with `nohup` will also work. This immediately detaches the `xdgopen` command from the terminal and redirects its output.

Comment: output to `/dev/null` is cleanest as it doesn't output anything to the terminal, thank you!

Comment: as per recommended by stack exchange, I tend to wait in case others may provide additional useful answers, though this answer will likely be the best one, thanks